# Very simple example for Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I'm struggling with [Spring OAuth2](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html). All I want to do is very simple, and I don't know where to start. All examples I found are never the same ones and I'm totally lost.

I have a login form, with username and password. When I submit the form, I want to

- Connect to an ldap server to check if the user exists (that part is done)
- If the user exists, I want to get an access token with OAuth2 to allow that user to access our API
- Send the following response to the client : {"username": "john doe", "access_token":"my_token"}

It seems very trivial, but although I read a lot of documentation about OAuth2, I can't find the way to do it with Spring OAuth2. As a start, I used that tutorial :[Implementing OAuth2 with Spring Security](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/) but it focuses only on server configuration, and provides no source code for the client.

Could someone provide me an example of source code ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you understand the concept of OAuth2 ? Do you have trouble to implement the server part or you don't understand how a given client could request your user credential in order to access your resources API ?

Comment: Yes, I read about OAuth2 here : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749
It's just that I'm very new to Java and Spring, and there are a lot of things happening behind the scenes that I don't understand/

Comment: there is so much to cover i suggest you take a look at this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) it's an introduction to the whole oauth2 principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a two parts authentication.

- First you will do a `HTTP Get` in order to get the code. So the client will be redirected to the authentication server.

  Once he enters login/ passwords and successfully authenticate to the Oauth2 app he will be redirected back to his client app with the code added as a parameter in the URL.
- The client gets the code from the URL and calls back the authentication server with a `HTTP POST` with the code as request parameter and he will get the access token in the response the access token is then used as a header to access the

The implementation of this process will depend on the client side technology you will use.

Here is an example of a third party Servlet that calls the Oauth2 application :

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        final String code = Strings.nullToEmpty(request.getParameter("code"));

        if (!code.isEmpty()) {
            this.getAccessToken(response, session, code);
        } else {
            this.getOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(response, session);
        }
    }
```

1 - First, we make the call to the servlet without the code parameter to call the method that will redirect us to the authentication server:

```
private void getOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session)
{
  final String oauth2AuthorizationUrl = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?" +
   + "response_type=code"
   + "&client_id=client-with-registered-redirect" 
   + "&redirect_url=http://client_host?key=value"
   + "&scope=read"
      try {
          final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
          writer.write(oauth2AuthorizationUrl);
          writer.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error("IO Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
      }
}
```

2 - Once we get the code we post a request to get the access token :

```
 private void getAccessToken(HttpServletResponse response, final HttpSession session, final String code)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod accessTokenRequest = new PostMethod(accessTokenEndpoint);
        AccessToken var8;
        try {
            accessTokenRequest.addRequestHeader(new Header("Authorization", "Basic " + "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token"));
            accessTokenRequest.addRequestHeader(new Header("Accept", "application/json"));
            NameValuePair[] params = new NameValuePair[] { new NameValuePair("code", code),
                    new NameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                    new NameValuePair("redirect_uri", " your redirect uri"), new NameValuePair("client_id", "your client id") };
            accessTokenRequest.setQueryString(EncodingUtil.formUrlEncode(params, UTF_8.displayName()));
            httpClient.executeMethod(accessTokenRequest);
            if (accessTokenRequest.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                this.toException(accessTokenRequest);
                return null;
            }

            // JSON response Object AccessToken
            AccessToken accessToken = (AccessToken) PARSER.readValue(accessTokenRequest.getResponseBodyAsStream(),
                    AccessToken.class);
            final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.append(accessToken.getTokenString);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IO Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        finally {
            accessTokenRequest.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

You can get your access token on the HTTP Response on the client side and use it to access resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand why you set the POST parameters manually (grant_type, redirect_uri) instead of setting them in a ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer ? (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/configurers/ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.html)

Comment: because  if you want multiple applications to use SSO with Oauth2 you will have different redirect_uri with different grant_type codes

Comment: as the comments mentioned it is easy to find multiple examples of this on the internet. google is your friend ( or DuckDuckgo if you worry about privacy) : [sample oauth2 client + server](http://www.jasondl.ee/posts/2013/a-simple-oauth2-client-and-server-example-part-i.html)